# Cant create table due to foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, innodb

I can't seem to create the third table here. Whats going on? I get the generic cant create table errno 150 message. Seems to have something to do with the foreign key

*Table recipe*

```
CREATE TABLE recipe(
    recipe_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (recipe_id)
)
ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
```

*Table ingredient_type*

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient_type(
    ingredient_type_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ingredient_type VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_type_id)
)
ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
```

*Table ingredient*

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient(
    ingredient_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ingredient_type_id INT(10) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    brand_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_type_id) REFERENCES ingredient_type (ingredient_type_id),
    PRIMARY KEY (ingredient_id)
)
ENGINE=INNODB CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;
```

Comment: `ingredient_type.ingredient_type_id` is `unsigned`, `ingredient.ingredient_type_id` is not.

Comment: Thanks a bunch... Cant believe i missed that!

Comment: @DCoder Make it an answer so it can be accepted and not listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

> Corresponding columns in the foreign key and the referenced key must have similar internal data types inside InnoDB so that they can be compared without a type conversion. *The size and sign of integer types must be the same.* The length of string types need not be the same. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation must be the same.
>
> **Source: [FOREIGN KEY Constraints in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)**

The problem in your code is that `ingredient_type.ingredient_type_id` is `unsigned`, but  `ingredient.ingredient_type_id` is not.